# Figuring out the manufacturer of a 3.5 inch tft?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, raspbian-jessie, pitft

So, the only place to buy raspberry pi addons where I live is an aftermarket which is not very well documented. I recently purchased a 3.5 inch resistive tft screen, with no information about the manufacturer, for about $25. I'm trying to hook it up to my Pi 2 which is running a fresh install of Raspbian Jesse, using [this tutorial](http://www.circuitbasics.com/setup-lcd-touchscreen-raspberry-pi/) and a few blog posts. The problem is that I don't know the name of the device or the manufacturer, so I cannot complete the tutorial.

[Here are some pics of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j77Gx.jpg). It uses GPIO headers to connect to the pi2, but gets stuck at the white screen.

---

### The Steps I have followed so far:

- Installed a fresh copy of Raspbian Jesse (from raspberry pi website) on my Raspberry Pi 2.
- Expanded my filesystem to the full SD card (I had some problems with the later steps the first few times I tried this)
- Performed `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` (in that order)
- Performed `sudo rpi-update`
- Rebooted
- Edited the file: `sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-fbturbo.conf` , changed “fbdev” “/dev/fb0” to “fbdev” “/dev/fb1”
- Since my Raspbian was after 1-31-2015, I entered `sudo raspi-config` and enabled SPI automatic loading and kernel.
- Rebooted
- Downloaded the notro files with `sudo REPO_URI=https://github.com/notro/rpi-firmware rpi-update`[EDIT: I did this process again but by using `sudo rpi-update` instead, no dice]
- Rebooted
- Edited file: `sudo nano /etc/modules` to:

smd-bcm2836

spi-bcm2708

fbtft_device name=waveshare32b gpios=dc:22,reset:27 speed=48000000

waveshare32b width=320 height=240 buswidth=8 init=-1,0xCB,0x39,0x2C,0x00,0x34,0x02,-1,0xCF,0x00,0XC1,0X30,-1,0xE8,0x85,0x00,0x78,-1,0xEA,0x00,0x00,-1,0xED,0x64,0x03,0X12,0X81,-1,0xF7,0x20,-1,0xC0,0x23,-1,0xC1,0x10,-1,0xC5,0x3e,0x28,-1,0xC7,0x86,-1,0x36,0x28,-1,0x3A,0x55,-1,0xB1,0x00,0x18,-1,0xB6,0x08,0x82,0x27,-1,0xF2,0x00,-1,0x26,0x01,-1,0xE0,0x0F,0x31,0x2B,0x0C,0x0E,0x08,0x4E,0xF1,0x37,0x07,0x10,0x03,0x0E,0x09,0x00,-1,0XE1,0x00,0x0E,0x14,0x03,0x11,0x07,0x31,0xC1,0x48,0x08,0x0F,0x0C,0x31,0x36,0x0F,-1,0x11,-2,120,-1,0x29,-1,0x2c,-3

ads7846_device model=7846 cs=1 gpio_pendown=17 speed=1000000 keep_vref_on=1 swap_xy=0 pressure_max=255 x_plate_ohms=60 x_min=200 x_max=3900 y_min=200 y_max=3900

- Edit `/boot/cmdline.txt` to:

dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait fbtft_device.custom fbtft_device.name=waveshare32b fbtft_device.gpios=dc:22,reset:27 fbtft_device.bgr=1 fbtft_device.speed=48000000 fbcon=map:10 fbcon=font:ProFont6x11 logo.nologo dma.dmachans=0x7f35 console=tty1 consoleblank=0 fbtft_device.fps=50 fbtft_device.rotate=0

- Added to `sudo nano /etc/rc.local` :

su -l pi -c startx

- `sudo raspi-config` and enabled loading into desktop GUI autologin by default.

Comment: 48 million bits per second SPI rate seems ambitious to me.  I'd try something like 1000000 (1 million) while you are testing.   All you can do is 1) try the settings for various TFT and hope for the best, or 2) google for similar images and try to track it down that way, or 3) post the images (particularly the back view) on as many sites as possible and hope someone else has one.

Comment: Did you check the seller's page?

Comment: The seller has no online page, they only own a brick-and-mortar store (albeit a reputable one) which is where I bought it. I tried contacting them, but they aren't really responding.

Comment: As I was looking for you problem I found similar LCD on github discussion. Look if this page: [link](https://github.com/notro/fbtft/issues/252) helps you.

Comment: Actually, I figured it out :D I emailed the manufacturer and they were kind enough to respnod with a link to the drivers: http://www.spotpear.com/learn/EN/raspberry-pi/Raspberry-Pi-LCD/Drive-the-LCD.html

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange - I see you have already answered your own question - which is fine by the way, so please feel free (if you feel you it is **the** answer) to "Accept" it by clicking on the "tick" icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, so I contacted the seller and they were kind enough to email me the link to the product: http://www.banggood.com/3_5-Inch-320-X-480-TFT-LCD-Display-Touch-Board-For-Raspberry-Pi-BB-p-958458.html

Then, I was redirected to this page (http://www.spotpear.com/learn/EN/raspberry-pi/Raspberry-Pi-LCD/Drive-the-LCD.html), which had everything I needed to install it. It works absolutely fine now on Rapsbian Jesse, trying on Ubuntu Mate with BerryBoot.

EDIT:

So, I looked inside the .tar.gz archive. I think my device was a waveshare35a after all! And the only reason it wasn't working with the tutorial I mentioned is because I didn't try it.